# Postfixで送ったメールがエラーで返ってくる原因

Tags: gmail, postfix

Postfixで送ったメールが下記のエラーになります。原因として何が考えられるでしょうか？
自分なりに調べていますが原因がわかっていません。
送信先のアドレスはGmailではありません。

```
Hi. This is the mail program at ns.netyou.jp.
I'm afraid I wasn't able to deliver your message to the following addresses.
This is a permanent error; I've given up. Sorry it didn't work out.

<***@gmail.com>: host gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.23.27]
    said: 550-5.7.26 This message does not have authentication information or
    fails to 550-5.7.26 pass authentication checks. To best protect our users
    from spam, the 550-5.7.26 message has been blocked. Please visit 550-5.7.26
    https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126#authentication for more 550
    5.7.26 information. t71-20020a63814a000000b0039d7613ebaesi1450017pgd.97 -
    gsmtp (in reply to end of DATA command)

Reporting-MTA: dns; mail02-you-outgoing.ns.netyou.jp
X-Postfix-Queue-ID: 6DA79E105BF
X-Postfix-Sender: rfc822; ***
Arrival-Date: Tue, 12 Apr 2022 11:54:09 +0900 (JST)

Final-Recipient: rfc822; ***@gmail.com
Action: failed
Status: 5.7.26
Remote-MTA: dns; gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com
Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 550-5.7.26 This message does not have authentication
    information or fails to 550-5.7.26 pass authentication checks. To best
    protect our users from spam, the 550-5.7.26 message has been blocked.
    Please visit 550-5.7.26
    https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126#authentication for more 550
    5.7.26 information. t71-20020a63814a000000b0039d7613ebaesi1450017pgd.97 -
    gsmtp
```

Comment: gmail はどのように関係していますか？ SMTP として指定している？

Answer (score 0):

`ns.netyou.jp` サーバーから `gmail.com` に送信したメールがエラーになったというメッセージなので、`ns.netyou.jp` サーバーと `gmail.com` サーバー間の問題ですね。
もし `netyou.jp` ドメインのメールアドレスに送ったメールがこのエラーになったということなら、送信先のユーザーが Gmail に転送設定しているのかもしれません。

Answer (score 0):

> To best protect our users from spam,

送信したメールをGmailはspam扱いしてますね。
550-5.7.26のエラーコードに関しては
[Gmail の SMTP に関するエラーとコード - Google Workspace 管理者 ヘルプ](https://support.google.com/a/answer/3726730)
これによると、「DMARC ポリシーによって承認されませんでした。」だそうです。
従来、問題が発生していなかったのであれば、最近Gmailの受信ポリシーが変更されたのかもしれません。送信元を次の記事を参考に設定変更する必要があるのではないでしょうか。
[DMARC を使用してなりすましと迷惑メールを防止する - Google Workspace 管理者 ヘルプ](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2466580?hl=ja)